# Getting nginx error 504 Gateway Time-out while uploading a csvfile through backend dashboard

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, php-7.4, http-status-code-504

I have been trying to upload a csv file through backend dashboard of my laravel site, but it's throwing an error , 504 gateway Timeout nginx . (This works perfectly in staging)

While looking for the solution, I have updated the following parameters.

In php.ini --->

- post_max_size
- upload_max_filesize
- max_execution_time
- max_input_time

In nginx config --->

- fastcgi_read_timeout
- client_max_body_size
- send_timeout
- keepalive_timeout[image]

While checking nginx /php logs its not showing any errors in logs , and also I have tried enabling slow logs, but still it doesnt show any errors.

Can anyone help me with this issue.

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1000s;
```

```
    client_max_body_size   100M;
    send_timeout 1000;
    keepalive_timeout  1000;
```

Comment: have you tried uploading an empty csv file before increasing the parameters ?

Comment: How do you use PHP on your webserver? If you're using PHP-FPM for example, I would advise to restart the FPM server process if you haven't done that already.

Comment: I am using php fpm and i have restarted it after changes.Same applies for nginx

Comment: In the staging , its a 5mb file and it tooks approximately 5 m inutes to upload, hence according to that only , parameters are set here